# Building 3s 18650 battery pack

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I got myself scrap laptop batteries for very cheap, only 2 cells out of 60~70 appear to be damaged (0v)

To charge 2 drained batteries, first I used a powerbank circuit that despite being less than a dollar does a very good and careful job at reviving low voltage individual pair of batteries, takes about an hour from 1.5ish voltage to 3.7 but it was taking too long so I put 220ohm resistor in series with whole 3s pack to a good 3s 12v battery, idea is to wait for batteries to hit 9v then take it from there, can anything go wrong with this method?

Then to balance the capacities for the pack, I will have to measure capacity of every pair or atleast 1 pair per pack which can also take very long, is there a quick reliable way to test battery capacity without fully charging and discharging batteries?

Regarding charging/protecting the pack, bms will cost me as much as batteries themselves, what if I use bms of working batteries instead, assigning each bms some extra pairs to charge and put all bms in parallel?

Comment: I don't think there is any shortcut to measuring capacity. Given that the batteries are old, I would recommend that you measure the capacity of every cell. Actually, I would recommend that you dispose of all your batteries and buy new ones. But barring that, I would buy a battery analyzer or charger than can measure capacity and test each cell. Your question about BMS is totally unclear. I recommend you draw a diagram to illustrate what you have in mind.

Comment: With a good adjustable CV,CC power supply, you can measure ESR and dV/dt capacity and match within 1% , but if don’t have a balancer for 5 to 10% of load the next weakest cell will fail sooner than you’d like

Comment: Can you provide more info refer me to some useful links? I am not gonna use it rough tho, my load probably will never exceed 100w @tony

Comment: I never found any links I just did it but 3S 20A  BMS boards go for < $3

Comment: if balance error is  50mV and ESR is 50 mOhms vs 100m at 10A then balancer must dump 5W per cell affected, So SoC cutoff a, dV/dt and ESR are tradeoffs with useage

Comment: I don't understand what you are said about the balancer @tony

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt322/slyt322.pdf

Comment: A lithium battery cell discharged to a voltage from 3V to 3.2V is damaged. Discharged below 3V is very damaged. Discharged below 2.8V is ruined and should not have an attempted charge. Read about it at www.batteryuniversity.com .

Comment: I am aware of that but i have revived few samsung batteries in the past that i still have and they outperform cheap 18650 batteries even after 2 years of usuage, if they are damaged they drop voltage within 5 to 6 hours sitting idle so i will take my chances @Audioguru

Comment: @Audioguru it is not that simple. What you say may be true for high rate batteries, I am not sure. But 10-15 year ago when I was designing consumer products with lithium ion batteries, we always discharged them down to zero volts and then verified that they could be revived with the device's built-in charger (by way of the pre-charge mechanism). I don't think the cells had full capacity afterwards. But they were by no means destroyed. The cells had a BMS attached. We defeated the BMS to fully discharge the cell, then re-enabled it during the recovery.

Comment: Battery University says what I said about avoiding a low voltage on a Li-Ion cell.

Comment: No one is denying it but it is not true for every discharged lithium battery and I have working revived batteries to prove it @Audioguru

Comment: Most Li-Ion battery charger ICs first measure the voltage of each cell then either refuse to charge with an error warning or attempt a very low current charge and stop with an error warning if the voltage does not rise. If your charger does not do these things then you are risking an explosion/fire. There is more risk each time a cell has a voltage lower than 2.5V to 3V. Newer LiFePO4 cells are different.

Comment: When you drive or sitting as a passenger in a car there is a risk of accident which increases many times while speeding, there could be a venomous snake hiding in the grass of your backyard but what are the chances of these things happening? Very low and trust me i am not planning to sleep on these batteries, even if i intentionally try to explode them the only way i can think of that might work is putting them in fire @Audioguru

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's a nice idea to recycle batteries from old laptop battery packs from an environmental point of view. Depending on your planned usage I wouldn't expect too much from these batteries as they might not hold their full capacity anymore or might be damaged in another way (higher ESR, weak chemistry, ...).

To answer your question(s) more precisely it would be good if you could clarify some things:

1. how does your powerbank circuit look like?
2. what is this 220 Ohm resistor about and why should it speed up charging?
3. what exactly do you have in mind?

I don't think there is a shortcut to analyze the (remaining) capacity of your cells rather than fully discharing and then charging them with a suitable charger. The iMAX B6 Charger would be an example (there might be cheaper ones but this is a good quality charger used a lot from RC hobbyists).

Regarding the protection you must differentiate between protecting a battery pack or protecting a single cell. I would highly recommend doing both as there is the possibility that a defective cell will short and this is a problem if you put batteries in parallel because the whole pack will fail then rather then tripping the protection of the single defective cell.

Please provide more information about your project like a sketch/schematic. Otherwise its hard to guess what you have in mind and where exactly you need help.

Comment: 1. My powerbank circuit is just a diy smartphone powerbank that you can use with your own batteries (from romoss) hence i am using it to charge individual cells at a time

Comment: 2. I connected whole 3s laptop battery (3x in series) to 12v through a 220ohm resistor hence limiting current to 50mah max charging all 3 cells at the same time which is faster but is unbalanced charge just to revive batteries

Comment: 3. To have a 12v battery that is both cheap, from recycled material and have good capacity just incase if i need to time travel i can take it with me

Comment: You can do it like you said but I think you are doing more damage to the 18650 cells than actually reviving them for later use with the methods you described. 

It is for sure possible to build a functional battery pack out of recycled cells but this needs a little bit more effort than just connecting 3S cells to 12 V through 220 Ohm with a powerbank circuit??? 

I would recommend that you get more familiar with 18650 batteries and their properties in general. For ex. for proper operation you need to follow a predefined charging profile regarding voltage and current, namely CC-CV.

Comment: Powerbank circuit charges one 18650 or few in parallel but for it to recognize the battery and start proper charging, i am using resistor method to bulk revive 3 batteries at once (not fully charge) then i will use charger to actually charge them, then test them later, question was if **reviving** 3 batteries in series is a bad idea rather than reviving them one by one

Comment: A charger circuit refuses to charge a lithium cell if its voltage is too low for safety, because a cell with a voltage less than 2.5V to 3V might have some lithium plating inside which could cause it to explode if it is charged. Without using a balancer for charging then the strongest cell becomes over-charged first then explodes.

Comment: Got it now. I think it is a bad idea to revive 3 cells in series because then you don't know what is happening with the individual cells unless you would measure the voltage over all cells - then it might be ok. Either way, I would be careful because working with old 18650 cells can get nasty like Audioguru said already. They are not as safe as NiMH, NiCd or Lead-Acid batteries.

Comment: Lead-Acid batteries are insanely dangerous, they shower hot acid when they explode, increased chance of getting injured @Ostelbach

Comment: ALL my Li-ion and Li-PO powered products have a circuit that prevents discharging each cell below 3.0V and have a proper balanced charger IC circuit. Your circuits probably don't. My car has air bags and I use seatbelts, You probably don't.